# Bash ls command not working in shell script

Tags: bash, ls

I'm writing a shell script, and it also has to check if a file with a certain extension exists in a different directory. I'm running an `ls` command like this:

```sh
TEMPLATE_FOLDER="$HOME/Downloads/" # Folder to check
file="py" # Extension only
amount_files=$(ls -1 "${TEMPLATE_FOLDER}*.${file}" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) # How many files in the directory
```

It keeps telling me that `ls: /Users/hussein/Downloads/*.py: No such file or directory` even though when I copy that exact path into the terminal itself, it works perfectly fine.

If anyone can help with this, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ls -1 "${TEMPLATE_FOLDER}*.${file}"
> ```

Globs are not expanded if they're quoted. Try:

```
ls -1 "${TEMPLATE_FOLDER}"*."${file}"
```